# Why is my JPG image quality (colors) darker after saving compared to original file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I load a JPG image into a System.Drawing.Image object, then I resize, then save. After saving, I noticed the color quality is much darker than the original. How do I retain the original, brighter,  color quality?

Using VS2010 (VB.Net), and I have tried using EncoderParameters as follows:

```
Encoder.Quality = 100L
Encoder.ColorDepth = 24
Encoder.Compression = CompressionNone
```

This is a "simplified" version of the code I wrote. All the most important parts are here.

```
'***************************************
' Constants
'***************************************
Const DECREASE_RATIO As Double = 10.0

'***************************************
' Initialize Variables
'***************************************
Dim dblRatio As Double = (100 - DECREASE_RATIO) * 0.01
Dim objGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
Dim imgJPEG_Current As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing
Dim imgJPEG_New As System.Drawing.Bitmap = Nothing
Dim objJPGCodec As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = Nothing
Dim arrEncoderParameters = New Imaging.EncoderParameters(3)

'***************************************
' Default Values
'***************************************
With arrEncoderParameters
    .Param(0) = New Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L)
    .Param(1) = New Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 24)
    .Param(2) = New Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.Compression, Imaging.EncoderValue.CompressionNone)
End With

'***************************************
' Get JPEG Codec
'***************************************
For Each objCodec As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo In Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
    If (objCodec.FormatID = Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid) Then
        objJPGCodec = objCodec
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'***************************************
' Load Current Image To Process
'***************************************
imgJPEG_Current = Image.FromFile(strFilePhysicalPath_Original, False)

'***************************************
' Create Clone Of Current Image Resized Using New Size Ratio
'***************************************
imgJPEG_New = New Bitmap(CInt(imgJPEG_Current.Width * dblRatio), CInt(imgJPEG_Current.Height * dblRatio), imgJPEG_Current.PixelFormat)
objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgJPEG_New)
With objGraphics
    .SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    .InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High
    .PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
    .CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    .DrawImage(imgJPEG_Current, 0, 0, imgJPEG_New.Width, imgJPEG_New.Height)
    .Dispose()
End With

'***************************************
' Save New JPG File To Disk
'***************************************
imgJPEG_New.Save(strFilePhysicalPath_Delta, objJPGCodec, arrEncoderParameters)
```

I expected a smaller JPG file in dimensions but retaining the same color quality as the original. Instead, I get a smaller JPG file with darker colors that appear less vibrant.

Comment: You might need `True` instead of `False` in `imgJPEG_Current = Image.FromFile(strFilePhysicalPath_Original, False)`.

Comment: O...M...G... I can't believe it was that simple, I completely overlooked that parameter.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) You can accept this question as a duplicate of the one I indicated if you want to, rather than deleting it.